# how to open ionic select programatically

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi i am trying to open the ionic select element programatically.
i was able to open the select by calling this method from the controller but once the native select show up it diapers again quickly.

I need to keep the select open until the user make a selection

```
$scope.triggerIntervalSelect = function () {
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initMouseEvent("mousedown");
    element = document.getElementById("intervalSelect");
    console.log(element.dispatchEvent(e));
}
```

what i'm trying to achieve is making the select element invisible to the users but trigger it by selecting an list item so they can make a selection.

i've been following this example.http://fiddlesalad.com/javascript/open-select-programmatically/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AngularJS directive ng-repeat to go through your JSON data after you linked your data to a scope variable. If you use a service or something, the select can be updated automatically once it's binded to the scope variable.

I made a small codepen to show you : codepen.io/akyh/pen/rBpAy?editors=101154
When you click the upper button, it adds one element to my JSON data and it's automatically refreshed in the view.

I hope that's what you were looking for.